# Managing Autorotation in Windows 8 metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

How can i manage Autorotation Windows 8 Apps.
I have gone through the "Rotation" Sample from MSDN but it is hell lot confusing, what I need to do is , I need to have completely different view when in Portrait and a diiferent one in Landscape.
I have designed my view for Landscape when I need to make changes for Portrait View. I need a way to dynamically switch between to views of re-shuffle the views.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample app templates, especially the Grid App template, and see how they do it? I learned loads from that sample template. It does some layout changes just by changing properties (margins and such), and others -- particularly Snap view -- by replacing the UI entirely. Definitely worth studying if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the *easiest* way to deal with this is to inherit your page from **LayoutAwarePage** instead of **Page** and leverage the Visual State Manager inside of Expression Blend to do all of the work for you.

I have a full article with lots of pictures and a downloadable sample application here:

http://jaredbienz.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/wp-to-w8-view-states-using-visual-state-manager/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to want to use a FlipView control here.  I don't know if you're using JavaScript/HTML5 or C#/XAML, but it is available in either case.

There's a great sample on MSDN to show you how to do it, but without more context on your issue, I don't know how much more I can assist.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/FlipView-control-sample-18e434b4

Answer (score 0):

You can handle orientation changes in two basic ways...

1) The brute force approach.  Wire into the orientationchanged event...

```
            Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged += DisplayProperties_OrientationChanged;
```

In the event handle, check the orientation and navigate to a page that has been specifically layout out for that orientation...

```
if (Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PortraitPage));
```

Pros... easy to design pages optimized for given orientations
Cons... need to handle navigation and state data between pages

2)  Create a single page that changes its layout using visual states.  You would still wire into the orientationchanged event, but make calls to `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this,"Portrait",true).`or something similar depending on how you name your visual states.

Pros... change layout without navigation and you can add cool animations easily
Cons... more complex layout could be harder if you are not comfortable with advanced xaml layouts and viewStates

If you look at the sample templates (besides blank) they include a LayoutAwarePage that handles the viewstate transitions for you, simplifying things a bit.